# File Input Stream not working on Api level 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio, m3u

I have a method that tries to extract m3u files, but it doesn't work at api level 29. I get the following error on the Logcat screen:

```
2019-10-03 20:46:53.165 32591-417/? E/Google: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to mysite.tk not permitted
```

My Method:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class _loadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try { //new FileInputStream (new File(name)
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(strings[0])); // if u r trying to open file from asstes InputStream is = getassets.open(); InputStream
            M3UPlaylist playlist = parser.parseFile(is);
            mAdapter.update(playlist.getPlaylistItems());

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Google", "_loadFile: " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**EDİT:**

I gave ClearText permission, but a new error appeared.

```
Google: _loadFile: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Netuptv/data.m3u: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**EDİT:**

My file path. I think the problem is here. But I don't have the information to solve it.

```
   static final File DEFA = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    public static final File dir = new File(DEFA.getPath() + "/Netuptv");
    static final File filepath = new File(dir.getPath() + "/data.m3u");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Android 10 (api level 29) file access is deprecated, it's called `scoped storage`.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371742/2944616 Remember to accept the right reply, stack overflow is not a simple forum. Thanks.

Comment: I'm new, I don't know what to do. Can you share code?

Comment: It's the reason why I said to accept the response if it works for you, it's how stackoverflow works

Comment: I haven't started it yet. I will accept the right answer if I can. But I need to be sure before it's true.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you added this line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your Manifest.

Since the file access API is deprecated on Android Q, I highly recommend to you to read this [article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html) by **CommaneWare** , as mention on this article, try to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to avoid the file access issues

Try the following :

```
        String fileName = "data.m3u";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
                        + "/Netuptv");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File file = new File(storageDir,fileName);
            filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

Comment: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.

Comment: @jonyiash you need to set the `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to **29**

Comment: Yeah, I got it. then added "android: requestLegacyExternalStorage =" true " , but same error /storage/emulated/0/Netuptv/data.m3u: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: what can I do? Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @jonyiash ,I've update my answer, try using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

A quick but not permanent fix for testing on Android 11:

Adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

and changing

`compileSdkVersion 29`
`targetSdkVersion 29`

both to 29 in `build.gradle`